# how word2vec model integrating with lstm model?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, word2vec

For a natural language processing (NLP) task one often uses word2vec vectors as an embedding for the words.however i still dont understand how word2vec model integrating with lstm model?

How should such unknown words be handled when modeling a NLP task such as sentiment prediction using a long short-term (LSTM) network?

Answer (score 1):

To use text data as input of a Neural Network you tipically need to convert it to numbers, `word2vec` does that in a nutshell, as an alternative to having a big one-hot-encoded vector.

But to be able to use it, you will also need a dictionary, that is just a set of known words, that will be mapped to your embedding matrix (the generated word2vec). That matrix will have as shape the dictionary size and the size of the embeddings (your feature vector size).

That dictionary handles unknown words with a special token (e.g. `<UNK>`), that also has an entry in your embedding matrix.

**edit:** Added example

Lets say this is your input text: `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`

And this is your dictionary (size 8):

```
<EOF> 0
<UNK> 1
the   2
fox   3
jumps 4
over  5
lazy  6
dog   7
```

The embedding matrix with the embedding size 2:

```
0 | -0.88930951349  -1.62185932033
1 | -0.11004085279  0.552127884563
2 | 0.689740990506  0.834548005211
3 | -0.7228834693   0.633890390277
4 | -1.47636106953  -0.20830548073
5 | 1.08289425079   0.211504860598
6 | -0.626065160814 0.505306007423
7 | 1.91239085331   -0.102223754095
```

Then you will need to preprocess the input, replacing every word with the index in the dictionary, the result looks like this:

`[2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 7]`

Notice that as `quick` and `brown` are not in the dictionary, those are unknown words.

And finally to use it in the network, you will need to replace the indexes with the embeddings.

```
[[0.689740990506, 0.834548005211], [-0.11004085279, 0.552127884563],
 [-0.11004085279, 0.552127884563], [-0.7228834693, 0.633890390277],
 [-1.47636106953, -0.20830548073], [1.08289425079, 0.211504860598],
 [0.689740990506, 0.834548005211], [-0.626065160814, 0.505306007423],
 [1.91239085331, -0.102223754095]]
```

Comment: but i cant understand how lstm and his gates and activation function  is considered?? all the things you mentioned happend in first layer??

Comment: I recommend you to read Christoper Olah's blog, he has really good in-deep explanations of neural networks, including lstms http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/.

Comment: Said that, you can think of a neural network layer as a transformation of a vector to a different representation, one that is more suitable for the objective function. When you have a very deep network, a big part of the network will be doing feature extraction, and only the last part will do the actual objective (classification, regression, etc). `word2vec` will just do part of the feature engineering beforehand, reducing the amount of trainning/capacity that the network need to achieve the same effect.